Angular currency Mask how to input from right to left
import { createMask, InputmaskOptions } from "@ngneat/input-mask";

export const createCurrencyMask = (prefix: string = 'MYR'): InputmaskOptions<string> => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`[${prefix},\\s]`, 'g');
  return createMask({
    alias: 'numeric',
    groupSeparator: ',',
    digits: 2,
    digitsOptional: false,
    prefix: `${ prefix } `,
    placeholder: '0',
    parser: (value: string) => Number(value.replace(regex, ''))
  });
};

Hello there, i would like to ask how to only allow user to input from right to left? as this is mainly for price

You can try setting the numericInput property to true. This might give you the desired result.
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { createMask } from '@ngneat/input-mask';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  regex = new RegExp(`[${'$'},\\s]`, 'g');
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  mask = createMask<any>({
    alias: 'numeric',
    groupSeparator: ',',
    digits: 2,
    digitsOptional: false,
    prefix: `${'$'} `,
    numericInput: true,
    positionCaretOnClick: 'select',
    placeholder: '0',
    parser: (value: string) => Number(value.replace(this.regex, '')),
  });
}

Stackblitz Demo

It works. Is it possible that we implement method that user is not allowed to click on in the middle of the number to change it. For example, 21,00.22. If user want to change to 2111.22 they will have to change from all the way instead of after the .

@anscomooi updated my answer!
